# Cross-browser method of using the transform:scale css property?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following css rules:

```
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
     -moz-transform: scale(0.5);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: scale(0.5);  /* IE9 */
       -o-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Opera 10.5+ */
          transform: scale(0.5);
```

Which I intend to apply to a div in order to scale it, including all its contents, images, etc, to 50% its size while keeping the same center. As you probably know the rules I listed do exactly that, except for IE7-8.

According to [this site](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/), the equivalent, MS proprietary rule would be:

```
   /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

   /* IE6 and 7 */ 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=0.5,
            M12=0,
            M21=0,
            M22=0.5,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

However these don't seem to actually resize the contents of the div, it seems to shift its position but that is all.

[CSS3Please.com](http://css3please.com/) reports different matrix values to be the equivalent for scale(0.5):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
                     M11=0.9999619230641713, M12=-0.008726535498373935, M21=0.008726535498373935, M22=0.9999619230641713,SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

I've tested these aswell, but the effect was the same; the div seemed to change its position, but the actual size of its contents remained unchanged.

Finally I've tried [transformie.js](https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie), which calculates the matrix via [sylvester.js](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) automatically as you assign the transform property, but the end result was still:

```
M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5
```

Exactly the same as the one I tried first, which seemingly did do nothing other than shift the position of the div.

I *would* try [cssSandpaper.js](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/), but it looks pretty bloated for what I intend to do, plus there's no jQuery port and I don't feel like adding cssQuery to the project only for that. Chances are the results would be the same as what transformie.js generates though, because it seems to use sylvester.js aswell.

Edit: I also tried [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2010/12/07/using-modernizr-to-support-the-scale-css3-2d-transform-in-older-versions-of-ie.aspx) which seems to come from microsoft directly, and suggests the following matrix calculation method:

```
function resizeUsingFilters(obj, flMultiplier) {
    // If you don't do this at least once then you will get an error
    obj.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='1.0', sizingmethod='auto expand')";
    // Resize
    obj.filters.item(0).M11 *= flMultiplier;
    obj.filters.item(0).M12 *= flMultiplier;
    obj.filters.item(0).M21 *= flMultiplier;
    obj.filters.item(0).M22 *= flMultiplier;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not scale the contents of the div itself either. It looks like this may not be possible at all, but:

**How can the modern `transform: scale` be simulated in IE8-7, in such a way that it actually resizes inner div contents aswell?**

Perhaps I'm looking for something that doesn't exist, but I wanted to be sure. All the tests have been done using IE9 in compatibility mode for IE8 and IE7 (so far it has always done the job, I don't believe it's unreliable but feel free to correct me if you think otherwise)

Comment: Does [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) support this? [Maybe](http://modernizr.com/docs/#csstransforms)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Afaik (but someone may correct me if I'm wrong, because I have not yet used it) all Modernizr does is test if the support for transformations is there and let you know, but what to do if the support is missing is up to the user.

Comment: I've not used Modernizr, but from what I understand about it, that does not seem the use case. What's the point of that?

Comment: Well according to Wikipedia it is so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernizr#Running

Comment: Supporting something that is *unsupportable* like `canvas` is one thing. Look dude, try Modernizr; if it works, you're golden. If not, *forget I even mentioned it*. `;)`

Comment: The takeaway from that Wiki article is that *if Modernizr doesn't support it, it's probably not possible*. So you may have your answer in a roundabout way.

Comment: @JaredFarrish see edit; it looks like yes, modernizr is used mainly to detect features, not support them; either way I found a post by microsoft about what I'm trying to do and that didn't do it either :/

Comment: @BoltClock - Please explain the comment.

Comment: As per the Modernizr website `Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features in the user’s browser.` it doesn't allow support for HTML5 and CSS3 in non-modern browsers.

Comment: So if the method is not supported (ie possible)...?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: That means it doesn't provide a way for a browser to support a feature. All it does is tell us whether a browser supports the feature or not. Yes, really... apparently [they didn't think the name Modernizr was very well thought out either](http://modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills).

Comment: @BoltClock - Literally though, does that change the outcome on this question? If something is "unsupportable" in a particular version, what the frack is the point (in pushing the premise)?

Comment: So, bounty time. I really think it's just impossible in IE7-8, but let's see if anyone can come up with something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your explanation. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Env4/5/) in IE7-8 **scales the inner elements down for me just fine with the first set of code you posted** (though you indicate it was not scaling, only changing position). What that code does *not* do (and cannot do) is scale it from the center point (it is from the upper left), and the matrix transform cannot accommodate a translation (it only ["Resizes, rotates, or reverses the content of the object"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29)), so it is not "keeping the same center" as you indicate you desire.

There is a page I found similar to the [transformie.js](https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie) you noted in performing transform, but [this other page](https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie) speaks to the issue of the transform origin being centered. Ultimately, to get the appearance of being scaled on center, you must include a calculation of some kind to do a shift of the element using `position: relative`.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Env4/11/) I've made it easy on myself to do such a calculation manually by setting a `width` on the wrapping `div` and knowing the `height` based on the inner sizes. This could get complicated with any dynamic sizing, but [the link above](https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie) I believe gives the calculations to do it dynamically using javascript (JQuery) with the sylvester.js as well.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Indeed your fiddle is working fine; I'm going to investigate why is it I could not make it work with my page, surely I must have overlooked something...

Comment: So I implemented it again via jQuery and it is indeed working, albeit sadly unbearable slow for a large (100s) set of elements, I guess that was the reason I thought it was not working the first time. I will still have to leave IE7-8 out because I doubt it can be sped up somehow... oh well.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use IE's zoom property:

zoom: 0.5

This should do what you want it to do.

Comment: I was aware of zoom, but it is sadly extremely slow, much more so than transform: scale in most browsers, which is why I quickly discarded it. Thanks though!